# Facebook Page likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I know that the count that is shown by the Like button social plugin is made up of:

- The number of likes of this URL
- The number of shares of this URL
  (this includes copy/pasting a link back to Facebook)
- The number of
  likes and comments on stories on Facebook about this URL
- The number of inbox messages containing this URL as an attachment.

Does anyone know for certain if the **Page like count**, as accessible from [this kind of call](https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola), is also made up of the above rules or is it a pure Like count only (i.e. only counts people clicking the Like button of the Page)?

Cheers!

Lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a Page, it's just the Like count that's displayed - that other list is for URLs in your website/app

Comment: Cheers Igy - don't suppose you have any doc reference on that do you? (yeah I know, Facebook ... documentation .. :-)

Comment: Nope, it's just how it works as far as I can tell - it wouldn't take long to verify by pointing a like button and like box at a Facebook page and looking at the number

Comment: yeah i guess i'll have to do that to be sure myself. foolishly hoping for documented proof from FB... cheers